# What should I use to optimize my c# code?

Tags: c#, math, sequence

I was doing a codewars kata and it's working but I'm timing out.
I searched online for solutions, for some kind of reference but they were all for java script.

Here is the kata: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGLmw.png

Here is my code:

```
public static int DblLinear(int n)
    {
        if(n > 0)
        {
            var list = new List<int>();
            int[] next_two = new int[2];
            list.Add(1);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int m = 0; m < next_two.Length; m++)
                {
                    next_two[m] = ((m + 2) * list[i]) + 1;
                }
                if(list.Contains(next_two[0]))
                {
                    list.Add(next_two[1]);
                }
                else if(list.Contains(next_two[1]))
                {
                    list.Add(next_two[0]);
                }
                else
                list.AddRange(next_two);

                list.Sort();
            }
            return list[n];
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

It's really slow solution but that's what seems to be working for me.

Comment: Start by reading you code and determine the complexity e.g. O(1), O(logn), O(n!), ..., then try running under a profiler to see the "hotspots" (search for .NET code profiler.

Answer (score 0):

The first rule of performance optimization is to *measure*. Ideally using a profiler that can tell you where most of the time is spent, but for simple cases using some stopwatches can be sufficient.

I would guess that most of the time would be spent in `list.Contains`, since this is linear lookup, and is in the innermost loop. So one approach would be to change the list to a `HashSet<int>` to provide better lookup performance, skip the `.Sort`-call, and return the maximum value in the hashSet. As far as I can tell that should give the same result.

You might also consider using some specialized data structure that fits the problem better than the general containers provided in .Net.